# Alternatives to installing Ubuntu from bootable USB and bootable DVD

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, macbook-pro, livedvd

I have tried to install XUbuntu, Lubuntu or Kubuntu on a MacBook Pro 2007 but failed. Indeed, it cannot boot from bootable USB stick or a live  bootable DVD.
the machine is: MacBook Pro - processor 2.16Ghz Intel core2 Duo with almost 4GB RAM.

So I have tried to boot from a USB stick and a livd DVD, but:

- Bootable USB does not show up on  Mac EFI boot nor on `rEFInd` **as a bootable device**.
  Details - USB stick is recognized, selecting it drives to this message:

> Starting Legacy Loader Using load options USB The firmware refused to
> boot from the selected volume. Note that external hard drives are not
> well-supported by Apple's firmware for legacy OS booting.

- bootable DVD appears on both Mac EFI boot and `rEFInd, but it is **not recognized as a bootable device**, while the macbook burned the iso on DVD!
  Details - selecting DVD, I get the following message:

> 1. 
> 2. 
>
> Select CD-ROM Boot Type:

*(Note that USB stick works on other computer, DVD too.)*

**Summary**: I cannot boot [LBX]ubuntu from an external device.

Is there an alternative?
I was thinking booting in Ubuntu from Mac OSX, or havinf an iso partition on the disk where i could boot from...

A suggestion? Anything I could do before i trash my old MacBook Pro laptop?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your "Bootable USB` is an EFI Bootable USB? Which option did you choose? Pick the other, recreate the USB, and try again.

Comment: The machine is old. I came across this:https://askubuntu.com/questions/931455/installing-ubuntu-on-mid-2007-macbook

Comment: @waltinator the "bootable USB" is an EFI bootable USB. Now i have spotted the problem I think: machie is old, EFI boot is 32 bits adn cant work with current EFI 64 bits boot. Needs to figure out if Rufus can do a 32bits usb boot

Comment: I have made 3 attempts in order:

**0 -** building a `bootia32.efi` by myself -> interesting project. _Failed_ / 
**1 -** Build a live `Kubuntu 64bits 20.04` bootable USB using `bootia32.efi` and `grubia32.efi` from Debian ->  Boot process works but cannot find the boot loader, stuck at `GRUB` command. _Failed_ / 
**2 -** get a live `Debian 10.6.0 amd64 i386` bootable USB. 
_Works_. I hope my laptop will have enough Ram and CPU to handle Debian.

Comment: I am happy to collect advises on whether building my own `bootia32.efi` in order to install Ubuntu 64 bits. Note that there is an existing `bootia32.efi` mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/931455/installing-ubuntu-on-mid-2007-macbook, but did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The EFI boot of this MBP is 32 bits. While the machine is 64 bit.
a bootable USB with a 64 bit Ubuntu will provide a 64 EFI boot. This wont work, the EFI boot 64 bit is not seen by the MBP.

The solution that worked for me:

- installing rEFInd from OSX
- create a bootable USB to install a 32 bits linux kernel such as Debian 10.6 (Ubuntu 18.04 has also a 32 bit version).
- Then from rEFInd, the system can boot from the bootable USB and proceed to installation.

Side-Note that, rEFInd 32 bits can boot a 32 bit bootable USB with a 64 bit linux kernel for installation. However, since installed, rEFInd is not able to load a 64-bit kernel. That is why GRUB replaces rEFInd for booting and loading.