# MacBook2,1 will not boot to Lubuntu

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, lubuntu, macbook

So I was customizing a Lubuntu 18.04 install for a 2007 MacBook (model identifier MacBook2,1) to get the best performance out of it. It's the best compromise between performance and light in resources OS for these devices.
Because that device's fan is dead and it turns off due to overheating, I ordered a new fan and decided to do all the Lubuntu setup on another device, a slightly newer 2009 MacBook (model identifier MacBook4,1), and then put the HDD in the older one.

So I created a bootable USB installer which was immediately recognised by the 2009 MacBook and I was able to install it.

I set everything up I wanted, then put the HDD in the 2007 MacBook, and... it does not show up in the boot menu. 
Of course, I thought my install was problematic or just that the HDD swap would not work, so I plugged my USB installer in it... would not show up either!

Both MacBooks work fine and the older one would even boot to a Windows HDD from another device.

I am stuck, and I don't want to have to dual boot from OS X.
Also, now that I know my installation is not the problem, I kind of want to get it to boot from that HDD because I did quite a lot of setup on it.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Since even the USB installer does not show up, maybe you need to change something in the BIOS settings?

Comment: Nope it's a macbook there is no "BIOS". It boots to Windows fine as well

Comment: Is there no way to change the boot order, then?

Comment: Does the Macbook even recognize the USB drive (in Mac OS)?

Comment: absolutely, of course, the USB drive is fine, just like everything else.

Comment: changing the boot order won't do anything I am using the boot menu

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly.  Your system will be Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE but still on-topic here (Lubuntu is LXQt)

Comment: You are aware that LXDE is GTK2, and will remain super-light only if GTK2 apps are used?  Did you consider the apps you'll use in considering what DE is best? as few GTK2 apps exists; why LXDE was abandoned as well as the GTK3 partially done port of it (*it was deemed too heavy*) and the switch to Qt5 & creation of LXQt via joining with Razor-Qt devs.  The base OS being light, only remains light when apps suit that base OS and you gave no details that showed that (and I'd not use LXQt on 18.04 as it's wasn't LTS)

Comment: Where hardware was patched to deal with *boothole* vulnerability, 18.04.5 & prior media will not boot; which is why [18.04.6 media](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) was created.  Lubuntu and other *flavors* of Ubuntu had already reached EOL at that stage; so no updated-key *boothole* media was created.  This may not be your issue, but don't forget added issues can occur by using EOL media.

Answer (score 2):

Macs with the model identifiers of [MacBook2,1](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBook2,1) and [MacBook4,1](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBook4,1) have 64 bit processors. However, not all Macs with the model identifier of [MacBook2,1](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBook2,1) have a 64 bit EFI, where as all Macs with the model identifier of [MacBook4,1](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBook4,1) have a 64 bit EFI. So, if you installed Lubuntu to EFI boot using a Mac with the model identifier of MacBook4,1, then attempting to EFI boot using a Mac with a model identifier of [MacBook2,1](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBook2,1) and a 32 bit EFI should result in failure.

If your Mac has a 32 bit EFI and you wish to install a 64 bit Linux, then you will need to install Linux to BIOS boot. You should still be able to install Linux to use GPT partitioning. However, the Mac will need to be hybrid partition in order to enable BIOS booting. Installation would probably be easier using a DVD, however using a flash drive may be possible. This would require a Linux installer that can be EFI booted, but install a BIOS booting GRUB. In the past, Debian installers were able to do this and may still be able to do so. Once you have a BIOS booting GRUB, you can use this to BIOS boot other Linux installers and then replace Debian. As you can image, the whole proceedure can get complicated. You can post a comment if you wish to pursue this further.

You might consider trying to install a BIOS booting 64 bit [Xubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://xubuntu.org/download/), even if this would require an upgrade to 2 GB ([which would cost 12 USD](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/owc/apple-macbook/2006-2007)).

I added the links below so I would not have to hunt for them in the future.

### References

[Installing windows on a MacBook Pro 15-Inch "Core 2 Duo" without Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406506/installing-windows-on-a-macbook-pro-15-inch-core-2-duo-without-mac-os-x)
[Newly installed Debian stuck on loading on MacBook Pro "Core 2 Duo" 2.16](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405913/newly-installed-debian-stuck-on-loading-on-macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2-16)
[Alternatives to installing Ubuntu from bootable USB and bootable DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279559/alternatives-to-installing-ubuntu-from-bootable-usb-and-bootable-dvd)
[Booting 64-bit Ubuntu Images on a First-Generation Mac Pro 1,1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001238/booting-64-bit-ubuntu-images-on-a-first-generation-mac-pro-1-1)
[Installing Ubuntu without DVD or Flash Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312264/installing-ubuntu-without-dvd-or-flash-drive)

Comment: I'll add Lubuntu did provide an *alternate* ISO that used the Debian Installer; but it was last produced in 2018-April and was never updated; so it'll use the GA kernel stack, will require a lot of package upgrades post-install, and won't boot on fully-patched (ie. *boothole patched*) boxes like all 18.04 *flavor* media.

Comment: @guiverc: I am a bit a novice with respect to Linux installations. With that in mind, I state that I have not a clue what your comment has to do with my answer.

Comment: You mentioned Debian installer; my comment mentions an ISO is/was available for Lubuntu 18.04 LTS using that actual installer; but I also mentioned the *caveats* with that installer (ie. it's very old & was never re-spun with later releases; ie. no 18.04.1, 18.04.2, .. 18.04.6 ISOs exit; only original 18.04 LTS release offered it.  I *upvoted* your answer; just added my 2c of detail.